# Мне нужно повесить на событие action два обработчика

Tags: php, form, action

суть вопроса такая:

Есть стандартная форма:

```
<form id="form" action="zakaz.php" method="post"
  onsubmit="if(this.name.value==''){alert('Введите Ваше имя');return false}if(this.phone.value==''){alert('Введите Ваш номер телефона');return false}return true;"
>
   <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Введите Ваше имя" required="">
   <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Введите Ваш телефон" required="">
   <button class="but">Заказать сейчас</button>
</form>
```

Мне нужно повесить на событие action два обработчика.
Сейчас есть один обработчик action="zakaz.php"

мне нужно повесить еще один обработчик telegram.php, 
чтобы по нажатию кнопки данные уходили на два сразу(поочереди)

Мысль вот такая:

```
form action="script1.php/?next_script=script2.php"
```

Comment: Делайте запросы через аякс поочередно

Comment: можно вкратце написать мысль?

Comment: средствами php это невозможно сделать?

Comment: А zakaz.php не может обратиться к telegram.php на бэкэнде?

Comment: Дык это один обработчик. Если надо что бы пост был и на второй файл то сделайте обработку в одном файле или передайте параметры курлом например

Comment: `$ch = curl_init('http://site.ru/telegram.php');                                                                     
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);                                                                  
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
   curl_exec($ch);` как то так

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант (если оба обработчика на вашем сервере)

```
<form id="form" action="zakaz.php?next=telegram.php">
```

zakaz.php

```
<?php
  // Обработка формы
  if (isset($_GET['next']))
    require_once $_GET['next']
```

Вывод закешировать по желанию.

Только небезопасно это все

Answer (score 0):

Я никогда не пользуюсь формами. Может это и не очень хорошо. Лично я на твоём месте сделал бы 2 ajax запроса. Я имею ввиду:

- Есть кнопка, допустим, "Готово";
- На кнопке 2 event listener'a: `кнопка.addEventListener("click", requestFunction); кнопка.addEventListener("click", requestFunction2);`;
- В `func1` и `func2` ajax запросы. Если не знаешь, что такое ajax - гугли. Есть решение в jQuery. Там всё максимально просто. Если ты сторонишься фреймворков - будет сложнее. Гугли - XMLHttpRequest. Еще есть fetch. (Так же можешь загуглить);

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример с двумя аякс запросами, если 1-ый выполняется, посылаем второй, иначе ошибка. Если вам нужно отправить данные формы в 1-ый скрипт, обработать и вернуть результат в виде переменной (или массива) для выполнения 2-го скрипта, тогда пример немного поменяется, нужно будет использовать `dataType: 'JSON'` и изменить проверку соответственно, во всяком случае напишите если это так, я исправлю пример.

```js
function show_error(err) {
  alert('Упс, что-то пошло не так, продолжение не возможно!');
  console.log(err);
}

$(document).on('submit', '#example_form', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // запретить стандартный механизм отправки данных
  var data_form = $(this).serializeArray(); // записываем данные формы в массив
  
  $.ajax({ // 1-ый аякс запрос
    url: '/script1.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data_form // и передаем их
  }).done(function(res) {  
    if (res == 'success') { // если всё кул, идем дальше
      $.ajax({ // 2-ой аякс запрос
        url: '/script2.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data_form // во второй скрипт можно также передать данные формы, либо просто вызвать скрипт без этой строки
      }).done(function(res) {
        if (res = 'success') {
          alert('Данные успешно обработаны.');
        } else {
          show_error(err);
        }
      }).fail(function(err) {
        show_error(err);
      });
    } else {
      show_error(err);
    }
  }).fail(function(err) {
    show_error(err);
  });
});

/* Что у нас происходит в php скрипте:
  $post = $_POST; // получаем масив переданный методом POST, данные формы
  ...
  ...
  if ($result = ) { // выполняем запись в базу или конечное действие скрипта где проверяем выполнение
    // если успех и всё норм, возращаем статус success
    echo 'success';
  } else {
    echo $result; // иначе вернем ошибку
  }
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="example_form">
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Введите Ваше имя" required="">
  <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Введите Ваш телефон" required="">
  <button class="but" type="submit">Заказать сейчас</button>
</form>
```